# Add attributes to all json objects with a regex

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I have a json array:

```
{
    "Tabelle1": [
        {
            "Nr.": "1",
            "Firma": "Alba Reisen/Versicherungen/Darlehen H. Kajtazi",
            "Rechtsform": "EIU",
            "Sitz": "Rapperswil-Jona",
            "Kanton": "SG",
            "UID": "CHE‑101.868.757"
        },
        {
            "Nr.": "2",
            "Firma": "Alybaba - Schischa Laden, Aly",
            "Rechtsform": "EIU",
            "Sitz": "Wil (SG)",
            "Kanton": "SG",
            "UID": "CHE‑102.012.121"
        },
        {
            "Nr.": "3",
            "Firma": "Bluamawerkstatt zur Linde Marianne Bislin-Lieberherr",
            "Rechtsform": "EIU",
            "Sitz": "Pfäfers",
            "Kanton": "SG",
            "UID": "CHE‑217.602.289"
        },
    ]
}
```

i want to add to every object a attribute and a value which look like this:

```
"X": ""
```

in the end the objects would look like this:

```
    {
        "Nr.": "2",
        "Firma": "Alybaba - Schischa Laden, Aly",
        "Rechtsform": "EIU",
        "Sitz": "Wil (SG)",
        "Kanton": "SG",
        "UID": "CHE‑102.012.121",
        "X":""
    },
```

I managed to filter the last attribute of my json with this regex, but i think i am still far away from a solution:

```
"UID\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

I am using the search and replace feature of VSCode witch supports regex filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making things complicated by using regex here. You can use **any programming language** to append that `X` element with `""` easily to each object inside **Tabelle1**. I used Javascript here for the demo. If you still need the regex then you can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/QdOqtH/1) one.

```js
const json = {
  "Tabelle1": [{
      "Nr.": "1",
      "Firma": "Alba Reisen/Versicherungen/Darlehen H. Kajtazi",
      "Rechtsform": "EIU",
      "Sitz": "Rapperswil-Jona",
      "Kanton": "SG",
      "UID": "CHE‑101.868.757"
    },
    {
      "Nr.": "2",
      "Firma": "Alybaba - Schischa Laden, Aly",
      "Rechtsform": "EIU",
      "Sitz": "Wil (SG)",
      "Kanton": "SG",
      "UID": "CHE‑102.012.121"
    },
    {
      "Nr.": "3",
      "Firma": "Bluamawerkstatt zur Linde Marianne Bislin-Lieberherr",
      "Rechtsform": "EIU",
      "Sitz": "Pfäfers",
      "Kanton": "SG",
      "UID": "CHE‑217.602.289"
    },
  ]
}
json['Tabelle1'].forEach(e => e['X'] = "");
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Select `"UID"`
2. Use menu **Selection** > **Select All Occurrences**
3. Press keys <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Comma</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `"X": ""`

Answer (score 1):

In case you use regex, you should use capturing group.

```
^(\s+)("UID".*$)
```

- `(\s+)`: Group1: matches leading spaces
- `("UID".*$)`: Group2: matches content of `UID`.

After, you use following substitution (visual-studio-code).

```
$1$2\n$1"X": ""
```